# ServiceReferences.ClientConfig use basicHttpsBinding or similar

Tags: windows, wcf, iis, silverlight, https

We're trying to migrate an IIS-hosted Silverlight application using WCF from HTTP over to using HTTPS.

We have the following problem:

When loading the application, we can see the SL loading spinner with blue dots that just keeps at being on "100%".

When debugging, I can see that in this specific config, `basicHttpsBinding` is not an allowed attribute, although being valid in other configs.

When trying to use `customBinding`, there seems to be a `security` tag mandatory. Adding it gives out the error that the `authenticationMode` attribute is missing. When looking up the attribute for that tag for the customBinding, there's a [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/security-of-custombinding) on it. However, even trying out the supposedly "default" value `sspiNegotiated` on the "optional" tag only yields that that value isn't known.

Stepping into the code to find more info about possibly allowed values does not seem to be possible.

This is the `ServiceReferences.ClientConfig` for the client that uses one of those services. The services also seem to be set up to use HTTPS already.

```xml
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpsBinding>
        <binding name="config" 
        maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                receiveTimeout="01:00:00" 
        sendTimeout="01:00:00" 
        closeTimeout="01:00:00" 
        openTimeout="01:00:00"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
            <security mode="Transport">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
            </security>
            <httpTransport />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpsBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://localhost/namespace.service/SomethingService.svc"
          binding="basicHttpsBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="config"
          contract="namespace.proxy.ISomethingService"
          name="BasicHttpBinding_something" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: 1. In Visual Studio, delete the service reference from your Silverlight project, and add it again using the HTTPS service URL. That should recreate all necessary pieces, including the right elements in .clientconfig. 2. Silverlight has been long dead with IE, so you should be aware that things started to fall apart.

Comment: 1. Tried doing this, but using the https URL when adding the service gives me the following error: "The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'."
2. I know, I haven't really been involved in this project, but got the task to fix it. If I had a choice, I wouldn't do it! :')

Comment: This document I think was helpful to you: [Custom Bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/custom-bindings)